# Bot Framework Facebook Messenger Account Linking

Tags: bots, botframework, facebook-messenger

Trying to implement account linking on FaceBook Messenger via Microsoft Bot Framework. This is what i did.
Hosted a Bot on botframework, which sends back a signin card.

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .attachments([
        new builder.SigninCard(session)
            .text("Click below to Sign in.")
            .button("Connect with Me", "https://6493.ngrok.io/login")
    ]); session.send(msg);
```

My idea is to eventually replace, `https://6493.ngrok.io/login` URL with a SSO backed web URL.

`https://6493.ngrok.io/login` is a sample node.js app, which has implementation for get->/login and post ->/login.get -> login , presents the user with a login form. accepts username/pwd.post ->login, when user submits on login form, i redirect to facebook messenger with an **authorization_code** and account_linking_token which is picked from the incoming query string.

Here is the issue i see.

When the connect button is clicked,

1. URL https://6493.ngrok.io/login is launched but it does not have, account_linking_token and redirect_uri as the 
   documentation mentions.
2. URL launches I dont have this information to send back a valid account_linking_token. I assumed that facebook wants a web based authorization url.

Comment: is https://6493.ngrok.io/api/messages your bot messaging endpoint?

Comment: Yes, it was a locally hosted node.js app, which has a login functionality. it actually is not the messaging end point.

Comment: I'm not familiar with facebook Auth, but after spending a week on authenticating o365 i came across passport.js; I think passport facebook strategy is worth looking at. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

Comment: iam using Microsoft BotBuilder node.js SDK, looks like its not creating the Signin Card / Account_Linking on the FB messenger correctly. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1207

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Account Linking Microsoft bot framework Facebook Tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926592/account-linking-microsoft-bot-framework-facebook-tutorial)