# Account Linking Microsoft bot framework Facebook Tutorial

Tags: facebook, bots, botframework

I recently started working on a bot for Facebook through the Microsoft Bot Framework, and one of the key features I need is a good account linking system. When I did research I could only find a tutorial for the Facebook Messenger Platform https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking
I was wondering if anyone knew of a similar tutorial for Microsoft Bot Framework or where I can find more information on this topic, or if anyone has advice.

Thanks in advance

Cuan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you are using the BotFramework, you are still going to want to use Facebook's account linking (as described at the link shown above).  To initiate the log-in, you'll need to create a custom message:

```
msg = new builder.Message(session);
msg.sourceEvent({
     facebook: {
        attachment:{
        type:"template",
        payload:{
            template_type:"generic",
            elements:[{
              title:"title",
              subtitle:"subtitle",
              image_url:"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Needle.jpg",
              buttons:[{
                 type:"account_link",
                 url: "https://www.someurl.com/authorize"
              }]
           }]
         }
        }
       }
    });
```

Comment: @Lars is it possible to integrate Facebook Account Linking and Azure B2C authentication?